# Serializing NHibernate Configuration using protocol buffers (M.Gravells impl - protobuf-net)?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, protobuf-net

Is it even possible and feasible without the attribute mappings ?
I'm currently using BinaryFormatter with ZLib compression which gave a nice boost for deserialization (3x), but still a tad slow.

Edit2: Setting up the configuration

```
    public static NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration BuildConfiguration()
    {
        FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.CreateDatabase(CONNECTION_STRING);
        var cfg = new FirebirdConfiguration().ConnectionString(CONNECTION_STRING);
        var configuration =
            Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(cfg)
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromNamespaceOf<DataMap>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
            .ExposeConfiguration(config =>
            {
                config.Properties.Add("use_proxy_validator", "false"); // bugfix nhib 3.2, see issues-2011-12-01.txt
                config.AppendListeners(ListenerType.PreUpdate, new IPreUpdateEventListener[] { new PreUpdateEventImpl() });
                config.AppendListeners(ListenerType.PreInsert, new IPreInsertEventListener[] { new PreInsertEventImpl() });
            })
            .BuildConfiguration();
        return configuration;
    }


    private static void BuildSchema(Configuration cfg)
    {
        new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true);
    }
```

Edit: Here's the code with everything -not-related- removed.

I doubt it's going to help much, as i have no idea on how to get started combining nhibernate config with protobuf-net (Hand modifying the NHibernate source is out of the question).

```
    public static NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration DeserializeConfiguration()
    {
        Configuration configuration = null;
        using (var file = File.Open(CONFIG_PATH, FileMode.Open))
        {
            configuration = new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(file) as Configuration;
        }
        return configuration;
    }

    public static NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration SerializeConfiguration(Configuration configuration)
    {
        using (var file = File.Open(CONFIG_PATH, FileMode.Create))
        {
            new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(fs, configuration);
        }
        return configuration;
    }
```

Comment: In v2 you can indeed configure protobuf-net without using attributes. I'll happily investigate, but I don't know enough NHibernate to give an answer without looking. Of course, if you can post or email a sample that I can work from, it would save a lot of effort.

Comment: The edit is welcome, but only really shows serialization - if anything, that's the one bit I **dont** need, since it will be replaced. I meant more: something that sets up tr configuration (even a small dummy example - not your entire model) since I'm not very familiar with NHibernate

Comment: Sorry @John - I only saw your edit now; I don't get automatic updates unless you add a comment with `@marc` in it

Comment: looking at it locally, I am dubious as to whether that is *pragmatically* possible - i.e. can be done without going insane. If NHibernate has an inbuilt save/load, then I'd be inclined to use that.